# MySQL MD5 query

Tags: mysql, md5

I recently imported over 1000 users into the MySQL database. The problem I'm currently having is that all the passwords aren’t encrypted. My question is how can I convert all the passwords to MD5 with SQL query (eg. UPDATE `wp_users` SET `user_pass`= MD5)?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: **DO NOT STORE USER PASSWORDS IN MD5**.

Comment: If you're fixing plain-text passwords, that's great, it's a huge problem that needs to be addressed, but unsalted MD5 is not the answer. With a GPU-based cracker that's barely better than plain-text, it's trivial to undo. Instead use a password-specific hash like [Bcrypt](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bcrypt). MySQL does not support this natively so you'll need to use another language to do it.

Comment: If this is WordPress you might be able to find a plugin that does this, like [this one](https://github.com/roots/wp-password-bcrypt) though it looks like there's [several options](https://wordpress.org/plugins/tags/bcrypt/) available.

Comment: Thank you so much guys for your help.

Answer (score 0):

You can use several MySQL methods for password encrypt:

```
UPDATE wp_users SET user_pass = password(user_pass);
UPDATE wp_users SET user_pass = sha1(user_pass);
UPDATE wp_users SET user_pass = encrypt(user_pass, 'salt');
```

Test it on [SQLize.online](https://sqlize.online/?phpses=null&sqlses=9c912610a8da437116f5a619afdaab61&php_version=null&sql_version=mysql57)

Comment: None of these is even close to secure. It's 2020. Use something at least as good as Bcrypt or you're putting your users at risk. MD5 is trash. SHA1 is nearly as bad. **Never encrypt passwords**.

Comment: Thank you much Slava.  It worked. I just had to tweak it a bit to UPDATE wp_users SET user_pass = MD5(user_pass);